# Simpleframework serialize elements name without conversion

Tags: simple-framework

I have to create XML from Java objects and I use the Simple framework.

My problem is I need to send some names in camel case:

```
@Element
String ChannelData
```

and the xml element produced is:

```
<channel-data>
```

Which is rejected by the receiver, it needs to be

```
<channelData>
```

I cannot find a way to configure this, I tried adding the name explicitly:

```
@Elenemt(name="channelData")
```

but without success.

Comment: 'without success' means what exactly?

Comment: that the xml sent is the same: <channel-data> and not <channelData>

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it.

I actuallt initialized the Persister with the wrong format:

```
Format format = new Format(0, null, new HyphenStyle(), Verbosity.HIGH);
```

Instead of:

```
Format format = new Format(0, null, new CamelCaseStyle(), Verbosity.HIGH);
```